# How to count non white space character in an emacs' region?

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I am interested in knowing the number of non-white-space characters in an emacs selected region. How to do that? I didn't find any "built-in" function for that. I guess I'll need to implement my own elisp function. And I don't have a clue how to do that. Any help or material is appreciated.

Comment: The number of matches to `/[^\s]/` will be your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need to write your own code; there's already function `how-many` that does what you want.  Once you've selected the region, just type <kbd>M-x</kbd>`how-many`<kbd>RET</kbd>, and enter `\S-` as the regular expression to match.